# creating object with different properties

Tags: c#

I am creating a pos system for retail store as a practice, I was stuck at figuring out what the best way is to order my items.

Each item has a few properties: name, priceA, priceB, priceC.

I was thinking to create an object like the following code, which should works just fine. the difference between price A, B and C is that Price A will be the price when customer go to the store and purchase the item; Price B for delivering to type A of location, and price C will be delivering to type B location.

So, my problem is that other than Price A, B and C, each customer will have it's own price, in this case how should I order my object?

For example:

```
Customer A : price A = 1.1, price B = 2.5, price C = 4.1
Customer B : price A = 1.2, price B = 3.6, price C = 4
```

```
void createItem()
{
    Item newItem = new Item();
    newItem.Name = "brick";
    newItem.PriceA = 2;
    newItem.PriceB = 3;
    newItem.PriceC = 4;
}
```

Comment: `Item` should have a method called `PriceForCustomer`. Pass in a customer or customer id, it returns a price.

Comment: Well, the first thing you should do is use more meaningful names.  Aside from that, you need to better understand and define your business domain.  Are these price differences static and managed as data?  Or are they the result of a calculation?  For any given "dimension" of data, that sounds like either different instances of an object or interactions between different related objects, not just a geometric increase in the number of properties on one big object.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a `class PricingPolicy` from which you create a couple of instances (e.g. a separate `PricingPolicy` instance for each Customer, or perhaps a shared `PricingPolicy` instance for a group of Customers).

Then the applicable `PricingPolicy` instance can be used to convert an `Item` (which in my view should only store "base" prices) to the *actual prices* for each Customer or Customer Group.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go with something like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public double PriceA;
    public double PriceB;
    public double PriceC;
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public PriceA;
    public PriceB;
    public PriceC;
}
```

In the program you can then create CustomerA and B with their respective pricing
and create a new item with

```
Item createItemForCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    double factorA = 1.01;
    double factorB = 1.2;
    double factorC = 1.6;

    Item newItem = new Item();

    newItem.Name = "brick",
    newItem.PriceA = customer.PriceA * factorA,
    newItem.PriceB = customer.PriceB * factorB,
    newItem.PriceC = customer.PriceC * factorC,

    return newItem;
}
```

Based on the info above this is the most simple solution I can think of. However, I think the whole solution you are targetting most likely will need some rethinking and some more design as already proposed by the others.

Comment: Another way to instantiate the item

Item newItem = new Item({
                Name = "Brick",
                PriceA = customer.PriceA,
                PriceB = customer.PriceB,
                PriceC = customer.
});

Comment: True. I didn't want to change benji's style, though. Getting to the implementation details currently seems to be more important than idiomatic code ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Said,

> Sounds like you need a class PricingPolicy

create a new class:

```
class PricingPolicy {
     public decimal Price;
     public string Title;
}
```

and use it as `List<PricingPolicy >`.

also read following question on code review asked by me:

[refactoring a set of classes that do calculation base on many parameters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5201)